# Zero length array works,and i can't change it

Tags: c, arrays

I discovered mistake in my code (C). I declared zero length array,and it works.Problem is I don't know is that dangerous? I tried change it to

```
char c[1];
c[0] = '\0';  //or char c[1] = {""};
```

but then it does not work. There is my code:

```
void TranslateFile(struct keyElem* guard,FILE* inpFile,FILE* outFile)//"tłumaczy" plik spowrotem
{
    char x;
    char c[0] = {""};
    char tab[100] = {""};
    char empty[100] = {""};

    while((feof(inpFile)==0))
    {
            fscanf(inpFile,"%c",&x);
            if(x==' ')
            {
                c[0] = SearchChar(guard,tab);//get char from list
                fprintf(outFile,"%s",c);
                strcpy(tab,empty);
                x = '\0';                //puts(tab);
            }
            if(x != ' ')
            {
                c[0] = x;
                strcat(tab,c);
            }
    }
}
```

I dont know is it  save or not and i dont know how to change it.

Comment: Why is `c` even an array at all, considering you only ever seem to want to use it for one character?

Comment: The fact that it works is pure coincidence - what you have is undefined behavior. Specifically, `c[0] = ...` (as well as printing out a possible non-null-terminated string).

Comment: `char c[0] = {""};` even the types do not match.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Yes and no. An initializer can be enclosed in extra braces. For example, `char c[1] = {""};` would be perfectly valid, and equivalent to `char c[1] = "";`.  If zero-length arrays are permitted (as they are in gcc, as an extension), then presumably initializing the array with `""` discards the trailing null character, similar to `char not_a_string[4] = "1234";`

Comment: @KeithThompson Did not know about that. Thank you!

Comment: `c[0] = x` assigns a value to a non-existent array element. `strcat(tab, c)` scans `c` for a null character which isn't there. You need to fix the code.

Comment: "I declared zero length array,and it works." --> What was output was then seen with `fprintf(outFile,"%s",c);`?

Comment: "i can't change it"  Why can not you change the code?  Try `char c[1000] = {""};`

Comment: @user2357112 I use array because i have to connect chars which function read from file.

Comment: @piotreqd: That makes no sense.

Comment: these are not zero length arrays they are of length 1, the terminating null character

Comment: @user2357112 I use array because i have to connect chars which function read from file.Function reads series of 0 and 1 from inpFile wchich are separated by space (00 0111 001 0111 etc.).When function reads space it search for char wchich is connected with series ( SearchChar(guard,tab);)and then it write char to outFile

Answer (score 1):

1. Zero length array should not be allowed. Which compiler do you user?
2. Use %c instead of %s in fprintf. %s needs a zero terminated char*, but your code has a char[1]. it might work in debug build when C[1] is '/0'. But in release version, the program may write a very long string into the output file until there is a '/0' in memory. If you must use a char array, declare a char[2] and set c[1] = '\0' in all cases.
3. "if (x != ' ')" logic is a bit strange. You have x = '\0' in the first if.

Comment: Your second point is incorrect. If `c` is defined as an array, of whatever size, then the expression `c` is converted to a pointer before being passed to `fprintf`. Use `%c` for an object of type `char`. Use `%s` for an object of type `char*` or `char[N]` (the latter will be converted to `char*`).

Answer (score 0):

The standard doesn't allow it:

> If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value
>   greater than zero. [Array Declarations - From the standrad](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

However, GCC Allows it:

> Non-empty initialization of zero-length arrays is treated like any
>   case where there are more initializer elements than the array holds,
>   in that a suitable warning about “excess elements in array” is given,
>   and the excess elements (all of them, in this case) are ignored. [GCC - Arrays of Length Zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)

So at best, all initialization values are ignored and you can't use that array in any practical way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it like user @wyc said.I wrote

```
    void TranslateFile(struct keyElem* guard,FILE* inpFile,FILE* outFile)//"tłumaczy" plik spowrotem
{
    char x;
    char c[2] = {'\0','\0'};
    char tab[100] = {""};
    char empty[100] = {""};

    while((feof(inpFile)==0))
    {
            fscanf(inpFile,"%c",&x);
            if(x==' ')
            {
                c[0] = SearchChar(guard,tab);
                fprintf(outFile,"%c",c[0]);
                strcpy(tab,empty);
                x = '\0';
                printf("[%s]\n",c);
            }
            if(x != ' ')
            {
                c[0] = x;
                strcat(tab,c);
            }

    }
}
```

and it works exactly.Thanks all of you for helpfull answers.Im begginer so i havent intuition for it yet;)